# Using cloc (count Lines of Codes) result

Tags: ruby, cloc

I am writing a script for my research, and I want to get the total number of lines in a source file. I came around cloc and I think I am going to use it in my script.

However, cloc gives result with too many information (unfortunately since I am a new member I cannot upload a photo). It gives number of files, number of lines, number of blank lines, number of comment lines, and other graphical representation stuff.

I am only interested in the number of lines to use it on my calculations. Is there a way to get that number easily (maybe by performing some options in command line (although I went through the available options and didn't find something useful for my case))?

I thought to do regular expression on the result to get the number; however, this is my first time using cloc and there might be a better/professional way of doing it.

Any thought?

Regards,
Arwa

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about CLOC. But it is worth using default shell command. 
Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358540/how-to-count-all-the-lines-of-code-in-a-directory-recursively).

 To get number of lines of code individually

```
find . -name '*.*' | xargs wc -l
```

To get total number of lines of code in a directory.

```
(find ./ -name '*.*' -print0 | xargs -0 cat) | wc -l
```

Please note that if you need number of lines from files with specific extension you could use `*.ext`. 
`*.rb`, if it is ruby.

Answer (score 0):

For something very quick and simple you could just use:

```
Dir.glob('your_directory/**/*.rb').map do |file| 
  File.foreach(file).count
end.reduce(:+)
```

This will count all the lines of `.rb` files in `your_directory` and it's sub directories. Although I would recommend adding some handling for blank lines  as well as comment lines. For more on [`Dir::glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob)

Answer (score 0):

@BinaryMee and @engineersmnky thanks for your response.

I tried two different solutions, one using "readlines" got the answer from @gicappa

[Count the length (number of lines) of a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662438/count-the-length-number-of-lines-of-a-csv-file)

the other solution using cloc. I ran the command

```
%x{perl #{ClocPath} #{path-to-file} > result.txt}
```

and saved the result in result.txt

cloc returns result in a graphical form (I cannot upload image), it also reports number of blank lines, comment lines, and code lines. As I said, I am interested in code lines. So, I opened the file and used regular expression to get the number I needed.

```
content = File.read("#{path}/result.txt")
line = content.scan(/(\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+)/)
total = line[0][0].split(' ').last
```

content here will have the content of a file, then line will get this line from the file:

C#               1              3              3             17

C# is the language of a file, 1 is number of files, 3 is number of blank lines, 3 is number of comment lines, and 17 is number of code lines. I got the help of the format from the script of cloc. total then will have number 17.

This solution will help if you are reading a specific file only, you need to add more solutions if you are reading the lines of more than one file.

Hopefully this will help who needs it.

Regards,
Arwa