# Rails how to get the row count from CSV fast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have tried length method to get the row count and it took at least 2 mins to return the row count. Length method is fast up to 10 000 and it's too slow when it exceeds 100 000 rows. Is there a way to get the row count with in 2 sec even file contains over 100k rows?

I have used the following code.

```
file = params[:file]
f = File.open(file.path, 'r:iso-8859-1:utf-8')
csv_file = CSV.parse(f.read, :headers => true, :converters => :all, :header_converters => lambda {|h| h.to_s.include?(' ') ? h.downcase.parameterize.underscore : h})
csv_file.length
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650517/count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file-without-reading-entire-file-into-memory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662438/count-the-length-number-of-lines-of-a-csv-file

Comment: AbM & seancdavis - 
I already tried above, no improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found solution, `CSV.read(file.path).length` is faster than `CSV.parse(f.read).length`

Comment: Your question is about speed, but there can be memory problem if you have over 100k rows and use `CSV.read` so I'm still looking for better solution